# spark unit test with mock spark session

Tags: scala, unit-testing, apache-spark

I have a method which transforms dataset from dataframe. Method looks like:

```
def dataFrameToDataSet[T](sourceName: String, df: DataFrame)
    (implicit spark: SparkSession): Dataset[T] = {
    import spark.implicits._

    sourceName match {
        case "oracle_grc_asset" =>
            val ds = df.map(row => grc.Asset(row)).as[grc.Asset]
            ds.asInstanceOf[Dataset[T]]
        case "oracle_grc_asset_host" =>
            val ds = df.map(row => grc.AssetHost(row)).as[grc.AssetHost]
            ds.asInstanceOf[Dataset[T]]
        case "oracle_grc_asset_tag" =>
            val ds = df.map(row => grc.AssetTag(row)).as[grc.AssetTag]
            ds.asInstanceOf[Dataset[T]]
        case "oracle_grc_asset_tag_asset" =>
            val ds = df.map(row => grc.AssetTagAsset(row)).as[grc.AssetTagAsset]
            ds.asInstanceOf[Dataset[T]]
        case "oracle_grc_qg_subscription" =>
            val ds = df.map(row => grc.QgSubscription(row)).as[grc.QgSubscription]
            ds.asInstanceOf[Dataset[T]]
        case "oracle_grc_host_instance_vuln" =>
            val ds = df.map(row => grc.HostInstanceVuln(row)).as[grc.HostInstanceVuln]
            ds.asInstanceOf[Dataset[T]]
        case _ => throw new RuntimeException("Function dataFrameToDataSet doesn't support provided case class type!")
    }
}
```

Now i want to test this method. For this, i have created one test class which looks like:

```
 "A dataFrameToDataSet function" should "return DataSet from dataframe" in {


  val master = "local[*]"
  val appName = "MyApp"
  val conf: SparkConf = new SparkConf()
    .setMaster(master)
    .setAppName(appName)

implicit val ss :SparkSession= SparkSession.builder().config(conf).getOrCreate()

import ss.implicits._

//val sourceName = List("oracle_grc_asset", "oracle_grc_asset_host", "oracle_grc_asset_tag", "oracle_grc_asset_tag_asset", "oracle_grc_qg_subscription", "oracle_grc_host_instance_vuln")
val sourceName1 = "oracle_grc_asset"

val df =  Seq(grc.Asset(123,"bat", Some("abc"), "cat", Some("abc"), Some(1), java.math.BigDecimal.valueOf(3.4) , Some(2), Some(2),Some("abc"), Some(2), Some("abc"), Some(java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf("2011-10-02 18:48:05.123456")), Some(6), Some(4), java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf("2011-10-02 18:48:05.123456"), java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf("2011-10-02 18:48:05.123456"), "India", "Test","Pod01")).toDF()
val ds =  Seq(grc.Asset(123,"bat", Some("abc"), "cat", Some("abc"), Some(1), java.math.BigDecimal.valueOf(3.4) , Some(2), Some(2),Some("abc"), Some(2), Some("abc"), Some(java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf("2011-10-02 18:48:05.123456")), Some(6), Some(4), java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf("2011-10-02 18:48:05.123456"), java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf("2011-10-02 18:48:05.123456"), "India", "Test","Pod01")).toDS()

assert(dataFrameToDataSet(sourceName1, df) == ds)
```

}
}

this test case fails and i am getting a FileNotFound exception:HADOOP_HOME not found. Though i have created HADOOP_HOME with winutils.exe in my system variable

please give me some suitable solution for this.